# How to loop through the values of a particular column in datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow

I want to loop through the values of a particular column in datatable? can anyone please give the C# coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi try below code snippet

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
```

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            //Create a new DataTable object
            DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();
            //Create three columns with string as their type
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 3", typeof(string));
            //Adding some data in the rows of this DataTable
            objDataTable.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Row1 - Column1", "Row1 - Column2", "Row1 - Column3" });
            objDataTable.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Row2 - Column1", "Row2 - Column2", "Row2 - Column3" });
            objDataTable.Rows.Add(new string[] { "Row3 - Column1", "Row3 - Column2", "Row3 - Column3" });
            return objDataTable;

`}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach (DataRow row in GetDataTable().Rows)
        {

            object cellData = row["Column 1"];
            Console.WriteLine(cellData);

        }


    }
}`

}

Answer (score 6):

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
    object cellData = row["colName"];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try below Linq based solution

```
var values = (from t in dt.AsEnumarable() // dt is your data table
             select t[ColumnName]).ToList().ForEach(your expression );


 or try normal way 

 foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
 {
      string value = drow[columnname].ToString();
 }
```