# Get number of columns that have certain prefix in DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a DataRow that is part of a DataTable that has a number of columns, and at the end of the 'static' columns there is a potentially infinite number of dynamic columns all prefixed with the term 'cat-'.

Is it possible to return how many columns have this prefix? And how would it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your question is 'Yes'

Comment: @RobertFricke Cut the sass, and give me an answer damnit! (joke). But really, how would it be done?

Comment: I would answer but in about 3 minutes you will have five answers, all correct :)

Comment: Use the logic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4302059/2654498) and re-apply to your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one of the five (hope so) ;)

```
var count = yourDataTable.Columns
                         .Cast<DataColumn>()
                         .Count(x => x.ColumnName.StartsWith("cat-"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I'll accept when it lets me.